# Dealing with full-screen crashes on Mac, using command-line LLDB

Tags: c++, macos, fullscreen, lldb

I'm trying to debug a crash in a full-screen Mac game I'm working on, but when I have LLDB attached it just causes the game to freeze when the crash happens, and I can't get away from the game - I need to do a hard reset on the computer. Is there any kind of tool or preference for doing this? The computer I'm using to reproduce the crash doesn't have multiple monitors.

Comment: A stupid suggestion - have you tried debugging in windowed mode instead of full-screen? Or is the bug related to full-screen mode?

Comment: Sometimes I can get away with windowed mode but there are a few where the bugs are specific to full-screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do two-computer debugging?  Set up an ssh account on the game-running machine, log in to it remotely (command line in Terminal) from your not-game-running machine, run command line lldb on your game.  (`process attach -n <appname>`)

In the past, with gdb, Xcode had support for "remote debugging" which was this arrangement (Xcode running on one Mac, your full-screen game on the other) assuming you already had ssh configured correctly.  I don't believe Xcode currently supports remote debugging with lldb - I'd encourage you to file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com/ registering your need for this feature if it's something you need in your workflow.

I'm afraid I can't think of any answers for you off-hand if you're doing single-machine debugging.